# Is there away to display a title for a Tabulator table?

Tags: tabulator

I have multiple `Tabulator` tables stacked vertically on a form, each providing a unique purpose.  I would like to be able to assign a title to each `Tabulator` without the use of a leading `div` element.  Manipulating column titles is straight-forward but I am unable to find anything within the `Tabulator` documentation which suggests a means of creating a table header to span the width of all columns.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could abuse the column group feature:

http://tabulator.info/examples/4.7#column-groups

"By creating groups in the column definition array, you can create multi line headers with groups of columns."

Comment: Thank you!  I made it work.  The solution was hiding in plain sight the entire time. Thanks again.